# TypeError: request.headers.entries is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, typescript2.0

My code has getting entries from the headers in the Request object.
`request` is of type [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request)

```
let headers = {};
for (const pair of request.headers.entries()) {
    headers[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}
```

Executing the transpiled code works fine in the browser environment but running mocha tests returns

> TypeError: request.headers.entries is not a function

My tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es7", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
My tests are written in typescript which uses the above tsconfig file to compile. 
Mocha version: 5.2.0
Typescript version: 2.2.1

My actual code:

```
export const getHeaders = (request: Request): Record<string, string> => {
    let headers = {};
    for (const pair of request.headers.entries()) {
        headers[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }
    return headers;
}
```

My test:

```
describe("getHeaders", function() {
    it('Should return headers', () => {
        let req = new Request("/testurl", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: new Headers({"test": "test"})
        })
        assert.equal(getHeaders(req).test, "test");
    });
});
```

Comment: But how you actually run the test? I mean `Request` doesn't even exist in node environment.

Comment: I am using `isomorphic-fetch` which does have this `Request`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `isomorphic-fetch` which is based on `node-fetch`.

When you run tests in node, you actually use polyfills of `Request`, `Headers`, etc. provided by `node-fetch` instead of native ones which we have in browsers.

So the actual `Headers` class used in tests is located in `node_modules/node-fetch/lib/headers.js` and unfortunately it has no `entries` in its implementation.

I think setting up a proper browser environment for testing would be the best solution to your issue but I have no experience in this topic and can't really help you with this.